# How to create a Tree View of PC's files with DXL

Tags: excel, dialog, treeview, ibm-doors, data-files

I would like to create a Tree View with DXL to read and select PC files (as .xlsx or .txt for example). I read some documentation, asks and examples, but I only found some examples on how to  create a DOORS DB explorer, or tree view with only PC folders (not with files). I read `TreeView(DB box, [void callback(DropEvent event)], int options, int width, int visible)` documentation, but it hasn't helped me much.

Is there a way to introduce any file located on the computer into a DialogBox in DXL?

Thanks

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the perm `fileName` is sufficient for you?

```
DBE fileName(DB box,
 [string label,]
 [,string initFileName
 [,string extension,
 string description
 [,bool readOnly]]])
```

Details explained in DXL manual, chapter 23 "Dialog Boxes", subchapter "Simple elements for dialog boxes"

If you need more functionality, I guess you have to program your own explorer, probably based on the "miniExplorer" and the "Folder Browser DBE" from smartdxl.com